# SUBMIT button triggers Ruby or Python scripts on remote server

Tags: javascript, python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, restful-architecture

***UPDATE: solved by using these two resources:***

- http://support.unbounce.com/entries/307685-Using-a-Webhook
- https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/can-i-access-twilio-rest-api-from-my-browser

---

I have two servers (one a paid service, Unbounce.com, and another Ubuntu one I built myself).

When someone fills out a form on Unbounce, I want to pass that info on to the Ubuntu box, which is currently running Ruby on Rails (but can ultimately run whatever I want).

**Would the way that I pass info from Unbounce landing pages (that only supports Javascript) to other servers be to use RESTful web services?**

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you insert arbitrary HTML on your Unbounce landing page? Then you can just point the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element to an URL that is handled by the Rails app on the Ubuntu box.

Comment: I should be able to do this.  I will double check.  Many thanks!